# Dynamically changing html element's class in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, web

I have a page i created using `jquery mobile`, the challenge i am having is how to add the `ui-btn-active` class to an anchor element on the page's navbar without directly doing that on the `html`.

I tried adding that in a `javascript function` that should be executed after the page is loaded but the function gets called without the desired changed being effected.

It however seems that the element gets the class added when i reload the page.

Is there a way of doing that without reloading the page manually?

Or do i need to add a function that automatically reloads the page each time a new page is fetched?

```
function init(){
    //called each time a page loads from the html <script></script> tag
    $(document).on('pageload', function(){
        url = document.activeElement.baseURI;
        //alert(url);
        setActiveBtn(url);
        //window.location.reload();
     });

 }

function setActiveBtn(url){
    //split url, get the last part
    var splitted = url.split("/");
    t = splitted.length;
    var gizza = splitted[t-2]; 

    switch(gizza){
        case "":
            element = $("#home");
            element.addClass("ui-btn-active");
            break;
        case "news":
            element = $("#news");
            element.addClass("ui-btn-active");
            break;
    case "sign-up":
          element = $("#create_account");
          element.addClass("ui-btn-active");
          break;
    case "retrieve":
          element = $("#sign-in");
          element.addClass("ui-btn-active");
          break;
    default:
          element = $("#home");
          element.addClass("ui-btn-active");
}
```

}

Comment: can you share the code so far you done?

Comment: Call init() from a `ready`-function, docs: https://api.jquery.com/ready/